# replace AC motor with DC motor

Tags: power-supply

I would like to use a 2 HP DC motor to run my hoist gear for my boat lift i am putting in.
Would use a solar panel to recharge the batterys.

the AC motor and the hoist gear spec are attached.

Would a 2 HP dc motor be powerful enough to replace the specified AC motor?

[image: ac motor]

Comment: 2 is bigger than 1.5, so...

Comment: Does the DC motor reach 1725 RPM, does it reach 6.1 Nm(@15 min. on, 45 min. off?)? Then yes, mechanically, else *maybe*, and possibly requiring (modification to) gears.

Comment: why did you use the `power-supply` tag when your question is not about power supply?

Comment: the DC motor is going to be used as a lifting mechinism to lift a #4500 boat out of the water. Will use for 5 minutes a day. Maybe 2  times a day.